# How do I make multi-page landscape tables in LaTeX

Tags: latex, tabular

The title is pretty much the extent of my question.  I am trying to insert a large table into a document using the xtabular environment.  If I wrap the xtabular environment in a landscape environment, then the bottom of my table gets chopped off.  Does anyone have any better suggestions?  Thanks

```
\begin{landscape}
\singlespace
\begin{xtabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
      some & stuff & ... & \\
\end{xtabular}
\end{landscape}
```

Tim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the `longtable` environment:

```
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    ...
  \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: nice. I had to do this today, and I used this approach exactly.  you can insert a \caption{} and \labe{} BEFORE the \end{longtable} if you need them.

Comment: Ubuntu 9.10/texlive seems to be choking on landscape--any thoughts on where to find that? A cursory Google seems to suggest that it's out of date, but lscape isn't working, either.

Comment: If your longtable accompanies section or chapter titles, then these will be rotated too (if inside the landscape environment) or be left alone in a preceding blank page (if outside, landscape call clearpage). See here for a solution with rotatebox: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452723/105075